# Gambler´s ruin for a Binomial multiplicative process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to calculate the gambler´s ruin probability in a generalization of the classic gambler´s ruin problem. In the classical model, the gambler´s wealth could be modeled by an additive random walk with an absorving barrier at $x=0$. In this generalization, the gambler´s wealth follows a multiplicative random walk instead.

His initial wealth is $W_{0}$ and his opponent is infinitely wealthy, so he never goes bankrupt.
With probability $p$ he wins the game and his current wealth is multiplied by the factor $(1+r_{1})$, with $r_{1}$ fixed and  $0<r_{1}<\infty$. 
With probability $1-p$, he loses the game and his current wealth is multiplied by $(1+r_{2})$ for $-1\leq r_{2}<0$.

If $W_{n}\leq0$, for any $n$, the gambler is ruined and the game is over.

After N trials, his wealth will be given by $$W_{N}=W_{0}(1+r_{1})^{S}(1+r_{2})^{N-S}$$
where $S$ is the numbers of success (wins), and $N-S$ is the numbers of loses.

As well pointed out below by @Minus One-Twelfth, ruin in the technical sense, $W_{n}\leq0$ is not possible to happen, for strictly positive $r_{2}$.
So, lets define ruin for an arbitrary positive small $\epsilon$ as being $W_{n}\leq\epsilon$.

What is the probability that he is ruined after playing this game consecutively N times? In other words, what is $P(W_{n}\leq\epsilon)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the gambler's wealth gets multiplied by a strictly positive number when losing (so $1+r_2>0$), wouldn't they never get ruined, assuming $W_0>0$? E.g. if the gambler's wealth got multiplied by $1/2$ each time they lost and they started with $W_0=1$, they would never have wealth become less than or equal to $0$, since halving a positive number will still give a positive number.

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth, you are right! I edited my question.

Comment: Nice. And maybe you could try taking logs to convert this multiplicative problem back into an additive problem, and see what you can get from that.